# Rango de IP VirtualHost Xampp

Tags: apache, xampp, apache2, virtualhost

Estoy intentando dar un rango de IP que puedan permitir el acceso a un sitio local y siempre me dice que tengo acceso bloqueado.

El archivo que utilizo es:

httpd-vhosts.conf

Y agregue lo siguiente:

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot c:/htdocs
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:8080>
DocumentRoot c:/proyectos/vista/index.php
ServerAlias dcmproyectos
ServerName proyectos
<Location />
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
Allow from 172.27.1
</Location>
</VirtualHost>
<Directory C:/proyectos>
Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Comment: Me parece raro que el rango sea 172.27.1.0/24, ya que no es uno de los rangos de red privada (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_privada), y tu hablas de un sitio "local". ¿Puedes confirmar los datos?

Comment: Es que le quiero dar salida por el rango de IP que tenemos en la empresa, dodne tenemos varios sitios Intranet pero al darle salida a este no me deja de esta manera

Comment: No me has entendido... en una intranet es raro tener ese rango de direcciones porque son rangos de IPs públicas, dentro de una intranet lo que toca es tener uno de los rangos de red privadas. Lo que me hace sospechar que igual ha habido un error tipográfico al poner la IP. Si no, significa que pasas a través de un router/NAT para llegar al mysql, lo cual no cuadra muy bien con lo de "local".

Comment: Es que tampoco te puedo indicar mucho, entre hoy xD! pero claro lo que queremos indicar es, que si proviene del rango 172.27.1 deje acceder a dicha IP pero me las bloquea todas.

Comment: A ver, si la comunicación proviene del rango 172.27.1.0/24 eso significa que proviene de internet (a no ser que vuestra red este MUY mal configurada) porque ese es un rango de IPs públicas. Y si proviene de internet hay muchos elementos en medio que pueden abortar la comunicación, como NATs y Firewalls y el primer paso sería revisar esos elementos. Así que es importante que indiques si la comunicación viene desde internet o si es (como hacías ver en la pregunta) "local".

Comment: Si pongo "Allow from 127" me deja entrar como entro por localhost, pero encuanto lo pongo por 172 ya no me deja entrar

Comment: Si no, por lo que estoy viendo creo que dar permisos a Xampp por IP no es como lo estoy haceidno, sabes de alguna documentación oficial?

Answer (score 0):

Para que nuestro XAMPP se vea desde Internet lo que debemos hacer es lo siguiente:
1. tener instalado el XAMPP (obvio)
2. ir al directorio C:\xampp\apache\conf\extra
3. abrir el archivo httpd-xampp.conf con wordpad o notepad
4. bajar todo hasta donde dice New XAMPP security concept

```
#
# New XAMPP security concept
# 
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
 Allow from all
     ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var

</LocationMatch>
```

y borrarle donde dice "Order deny,allow" y "Deny from all"

5. ahora cambiarle la direccion "127.0.0.0/8" por all para que quede igual que el ejemplo anterior.
6. guarda el documento y reinicia todos los servicios del XAMPP

   Ademas tenemos que configurar nuestro router/firewall, para que se redireccione a nuestro XAMPP para eso debemos crearle una regla que ya depende de cada router.

Suerte!